# Understanding Left Invariant Forms on Lie Groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a $n$ dimensional Lie Group, and let $L_g$ denote the left action of $G$ on itself. I am trying to understand the notion of left invariance of various objects on $G$.

I understand that for vector fields, the notion of left invariance. A vector field is left-invariant if we have that:
$$
(dLg)_hX(h) = X(gh)
$$
Thus, if we know $X(e)$ where $e$ is the identity of $G$, we can compute $X(g)$ without much trouble, as it is given by:
$$
X(g) = (dLg)_eX(e)
$$
Now, let's generalize this to differential forms. We say that a $k$ form on $G$ is left invariant if we have that:
$$
L^*_gw = \omega
$$
when I saw this, it seemed a bit cryptic to me, so I decided to write it out in full. Formally, the above pullback satisfies:
$$
(L^*_g \omega)_h(v_1, \cdots , v_k) = \omega_{L_g(h)}(dL_gv_1, \cdots , dL_gv_k)
$$
For any $v_1, \cdots , v_k \in T_{L(g)}G$. What does it mean for $\omega$ to be left invariant here? The above equality omits some details such as which points we are evaluating the pullback at etc. And once we have this, how can we show that the form at any point is determined by tensor we get at the identity?

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the right ideas, but the left-invariant piece is that

$$
\omega_{L_g(h)}(dL_gv_1, \ldots, dL_gv_k) \;\; =\;\; \omega_h(v_1,\ldots, v_k).
$$

This is where we get the equation $L_g^*\omega = \omega$.  The main idea here is that left translation doesn't affect the overall value of the form.

Comment: I see. But doesn't that make it so that the form is the same everywhere? It seems that if you define it say, on the identity, and left translate it by $g$, the tensor you get at $g$ is the tensor you get at $e$ , just with a different tangent space to act on.

Comment: @rubikscube09 It doesn't necessarily make the form a constant object, because it has $k$-many inputs.  The idea of left-invariance is that left translation doesn't affect the quantity of a form, but certainly changing the tangent vector inputs will change the value of the form.  In some sense, left-invariance does in fact make the form "look the same everywhere", but it doesn't make the form a constant.

Comment: Right. I guess my only qualm was coming from the fact that left invariance didn't seem to work that way for vector fields, in the sense that an object that does vary pointwise still varied pointwise if it was left invariant.

Comment: @rubikscube09 That still occurs with left-invariant forms as well though.  They do vary pointwise, but the constancy has to do with the pushforward of the vector fields. The idea is that the evaluation of the form at a point $L_g(h)$ compensates for the pushforward $dL_gv_i$.